# Null pointer Exception. java. hibernate

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I have a list which i have initialised. i get a null pointer exception when i try to add to it. does anyone know why. here is a snippet of the problem-causing code.

```
Employee e=employeeskills.get(0).getEmployee(); 
    List<EmployeeSkills> es;
    es=e.getEmployeeskills();
    for(int i=0; i<employeeskills.size();i++)
    {   
        es.add(employeeskills.get(i));
    }
    session.getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(e);
```

employeeskills is an list of objects(EmployeeSkills). EmployeeSkills is the a type of Object.

Comment: try to use your debugger.

Comment: How does the implementation of ``getEmployeeskills()`` look like? Does it really return a valid List instance?

Comment: thanks for the quick reply :) yes it does return a valid list of EmployeeSkills. If it hadnt eclipse would have thrown an error.

Comment: @user1438038 List is a interface, it can not be instantiated, i bet it returns an List implementation class. However OP does not create an instance of List implementations but just refer to the reference which method getEmployeesSkills() return, i think here is the problem.

Comment: getEmployeeSkills is a getter method of a class which returns a list of EmployeeSkills. Can you give me a hint on how to fix this?